# Latest change: ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 - Efficient?

Tags: mysql, performance, timestamp, limit

I have a simple save-log:

```
XiD (INT) what was saved  
UiD (INT) who done it  
TiD (TIMESTAMP) CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

With all three fields in the primary key - to make it unique.

I want to inform the user of only the latest log-line (until she asks for more):

```
SELECT UiD,TiD FROM log WHERE XiD=? ORDER BY TiD DESC LIMIT 1
```

But what happens if there are a billion records with the same XiD ?
Is the above efficient or will the MySql-server examine all the records (for ORDER BY)
 - And if so: How do I extract the single latest record of a log like that, using the least server-calories ?

PS: I havent implemented anything yet, so any alternative scheme is possible : )

EDIT:
Perhaps it would be more efficient simply to store (overwrite) who and when (UiD+TiD) directly in fields on the XiD-record (besides in the log), so I can get them directly, only looking in the log when the user asks for more log-lines explicitly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. <strike>No, the engine will not examine all the records for `ORDER BY`. It will examine all those records returned by the `WHERE` clause.</strike> Sorry, missed this *But what happens if there are a billion records with the same XiD ?*. Yes, the engine will examine all the records for the `ORDER BY` clause. [Here is the order of operations, as explained by Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm):

   > 1. FROM clause
   > 2. WHERE clause
   > 3. GROUP BY clause
   > 4. HAVING clause
   > 5. SELECT clause
   > 6. ORDER BY clause
2. IMHO, I don't think there can be any better way to extract the single latest record.

Comment: Alternative: Under EDIT of the question.. ?

Comment: @T4NK3R: Yes, that would obviously be much faster, because you will be referring to that distinct record. If you can do that, design your schema that way.

Answer (score 1):

You need index on XiD ASC, TiD DESC to do that.
Since UiD is not in the where clause of the query, and TiD is after UiD in the index, it cannot be used for sorting (which is indicated by filesort in the explain query results)

Comment: So if I just rearrange the fields: XiD, TiD, UiD (still with just the primary index) the "cost" would be less ? oops took too long : )

Comment: You can add secondary index or change the primary key to include tid before uid. Caching the last edited uid / tid also makes sense.

Comment: @Darhazer: What filesort are you talking about, he has a compound index of the three columns, where does filesort come into that?

Comment: @Shef the third field in the index can't be used if the value of the first two is not specified. 
"MySQL cannot use an index if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index"

Comment: @Darhazer: The column he is using for the `ORDER BY` clause forms a leftmost prefix of the index, because `DESC` will reverse the index. It will become `TiD UiD XiD`. So, `TiD` will come first, that's what he is using only. The keys used for `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` are different ones, don't mix them. :)

Comment: In MySQL, One and the same key is used for WHERE and ORDER BY
here is the EXPLAIN
select_type: SIMPLE
table:test
type:ref
possible_keys:PRIMARY
key:PRIMARY
key_len: 4
ref:const
rows: 1
Extra: Using where; Using index; Using filesort

Please, read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

if your 'XID' columns has '*AUTO_INCREMENT*' U can use:

```
SELECT UiD,TiD FROM log WHERE XiD=LAST_INSERT_ID() ORDER BY TiD DESC LIMIT 1
```

ref: [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: Can't: XiD refers to the data-record being saved (the XiD is fixed)

Comment: last_insert_id is per connection and is for the last insert that client has performed. It has no meaning if you connect to the server and execute it, without performing an insert first.

Comment: yeah sorry, @Darhazer is right, I've just reviewed and tested the code, this is not the solution